# fetch products from my AMAZON store

Tags: php

i want to fetch products from my AMAZON store. i created the code that fetches all the products using MWS AMAZON API (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html). my code is working and return the products. but it does not retruns the variants of the products. It gives an "ASIN value" IN relationship Tag. to fetch the the variants i make new api call by using that "ASIN VALUE".
is there any way throgh i may able to fetch all products from amazon with there all attributes and varients in single call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't fetch product and variants in single call you need to make other calls to get variants.